# How do I change the "Thanks for your order" message on paypal?

Tags: paypal

We have a new app that basically sells data. I have three issues with the automatically generated message from paypal after the order has gone through which we are running on a test server. It currently says;

"Thanks for your order
Your payment of £1.00 GBP is complete.

You're now going back to abc Ltd.

If you are not redirected within 10 seconds, click here."

The first problem is that I want to change the name of abc Ltd.
The second is that the redirect is not working
The third is that the link - click here - does not go back to the prescribed link, but instead regenerates another copy of the downloaded zipped up folder.

Would be most grateful for your any ideas and solutions.

Comment: What do you have the "return" URL set to in the transaction? Can you provide the code you're testing with? What about the redirect isn't working? The "abc Ltd" that appears is based on the business name of the account that received the payment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have figured this out by now.

You need to add a get variable to your payment link like so:

&return=http://www.xxxx.com/thankyou_page

For the "You're now going back to abc Ltd." I'm still looking.